# How to get particular data between two same marker patterns

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep, sh

Using awk or sed , how can I select lines which are occurring between two same  marker patterns? There may be multiple sections marked with these patterns.

For instance: Suppose the file contains:

```
$$$
lines between dollar and AT
@@@
lines between first and second AT
@@@
lines between second and third AT
@@@
lines between third and fourth AT
@@@
```

Using

```
cat 2.txt | sed -n '/$$$/,/@@@/p'
```

I get the content between $$$ and first occurrence of @@@.

My doubt is , how to get content between say **first and third occurrence of @@@**

Expected output is :

```
lines between first and second AT
@@@
lines between second and third AT
```

Comment: Add a counter, check counter, if counter=value, print data

Comment: As a start: `awk '/@@@/ {cnt+=1 }cnt; cnt==3{exit}' input.txt`

Comment: Perhaps also add the following to Fredrik Pihl comment, i.e shave the first and last line...
`awk '/@@@/ {cnt+=1 }cnt; cnt==3{exit}' sed_sample.txt | sed -e '1,1d' -e '$d'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` seems to be the saner tool for this job, largely because it allows you to specify parameters on the command line more easily than sed (which is to say, at all), and because it can handle numbers sanely.

I'd use

```
awk -v pattern='^@@@$' -v first=1 -v last=3 '$0 ~ pattern { ++count; if(count == first) next } count == last { exit } count >= first' 2.txt
```

This works as follows:

```
$0 ~ pattern {              # When the delimiter pattern is found:
  ++count                   # increase counter.
  if(count == first) {      # If we found the starting pattern
    next                    # skip to next line. This handles the fencepost.
  }
}
count == last {             # If we found the end pattern, stop processing.
  exit
}
count >= first              # Otherwise, if the line comes after the starting
                            # pattern, print the line.
```